# ASP.NET call an #id from a tag

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a little problem - I build a shopping cart checkout with 4 steps (with stepper and links to partial views).

Now I have to call a special #id (the attribute of tags) from the redirectToAction...

How is this possible?

the thing is - I'm in step 2 (partial view)  and call an actionresult, which redirect me to the "main view" - but I have to go to the 2nd or 3rd step.

Is there a way how to handle this?

Tried already to overload the button, so the href call the link and an onclick function() calls the actionresult, but this is not possible

Also tried to give the #id as a route value, but it seems doesn't work...

```js
<script>
    function goBack() {
        window.history.back();
    }

    //Initialize tooltips
    //$('.nav-tabs > li a[title]').tooltip();

    //Wizard
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function (e) {

        var $target = $(e.target);

        if ($target.hasClass('disabled')) {
            return false;
        }
    });

    $(".next-step").click(function (e) {
        var $active = $('.wizard .nav-tabs .nav-item .active');
        var $activeli = $active.parent("li");

        $($activeli).next().find('a[data-toggle="tab"]').removeClass("disabled");
        $($activeli).next().find('a[data-toggle="tab"]').click();
    });


    $(".prev-step").click(function (e) {

        var $active = $('.wizard .nav-tabs .nav-item .active');
        var $activeli = $active.parent("li");

        $($activeli).prev().find('a[data-toggle="tab"]').removeClass("disabled");
        $($activeli).prev().find('a[data-toggle="tab"]').click();

    });
</script>
```

```html
<form class="form cf">
    <div class="wizard">
        <!-- ============================================================ NAVIGATION ============================================================ -->
        <div class="wizard-inner">
            <div class="connecting-line"></div>
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                <!-- ======================================== Schritt 1 - Warenkorb ======================================== -->
                <li role="presentation" class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#step1" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="step1" role="tab" title="Step 1" class="nav-link active navigation">
                        <span class="round-tab">
                            <i class="fa  fa-lg fa-shopping-cart"></i>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <!-- ======================================== Schritt 2 - Ausleihdatum ======================================== -->
                <li role="presentation" class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#step2" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="step2" role="tab" title="Step 2" class="nav-link navigation disabled" id="schritt">
                        <span class="round-tab">
                            <i class="fa  fa-lg fa-calendar-check-o"></i>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <!-- ======================================== Schritt 3 - Rechnung- und Lieferadresse ======================================== -->
                <li role="presentation" class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#step3" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="step3" role="tab" title="Step 3" class="nav-link navigation  disabled">
                        <span class="round-tab">
                            <i class="fa fa-lg  fa-address-card-o"></i>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <!-- ======================================== Schritt 4 - Bezahlmöglichkeit ========================================
    <li role="presentation" class="nav-item">
        <a href="#step4" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="step4" role="tab" title="Step 4" class="nav-link disabled">
            <span class="round-tab">
                <i class="fa fa-lg fa-money"></i>
            </span>
        </a>
    </li>

    <!-- ======================================== Schritt 5 - Abschluss ======================================== -->
                <li role="presentation" class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#step4" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="step4" role="tab" title="Step 4" class="nav-link disabled navigation">
                        <span class="round-tab">
                            <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- ============================================================ CONTENT ============================================================ -->
        <!-- ======================================== Schritt 1 - Warenkorb ======================================== -->
        <div class="tab-content ">
            <div class="tab-pane active text-center " role="tabpanel" id="step1">
                <h2>Warenkorb</h2>
                <div class="row">
                </div>

                @if (Model.VmWarenkorbIndexListe.Count == 0)
                {
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <h1 class="text-center">Leider haben Sie noch keine Bücher im Warenkorb :-(</h1>
                    <br />
                    <h2 class="text-center"><a href="/Buch/Buchliste">Hier können Sie nach Büchern suchen :-)</a></h2>
                }
                else
                {
                    <div class="container">
                        <table id="cart" class="table table-hover table-condensed ">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th></th>
                                    <th style="width:40%" class="h4 text-left">@Html.DisplayName("Titel")</th>
                                    <th class="text-center h5" style="width:3%">@Html.DisplayName("Ausgabe")</th>
                                    <th class="text-center h5" style="width: 20%">@Html.DisplayName("ISBN")</th>
                                    <th class="text-center h5" style="width:10%">@Html.DisplayName("Preis")</th>
                                    <th class="text-center h5">@Html.DisplayName("Anzahl")</th>
                                    <th class="text-center h5">@Html.DisplayName("Zeilenpreis")</th>
                                    <th></th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>

                            <tbody class="border-bottom">
                                @foreach (var buch in Model.VmWarenkorbIndexListe)
                                {
                                    <tr>

                                        <td data-th="Bild" class="zoom">
                                            <img src="@buch.BildPfad" alt="@buch.BildAltText" width="70" onclick="location.href = '@(Url.Action("Detail", "Buch", new { buchId = buch.Id }))'" />
                                        </td>

                                        <td data-th="Buch" class="align-middle" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Für Beschreibung bitte klicken">
                                            <h6 class="nomargin text-left" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#buch">@buch.Titel</h6>
                                            <p class="collapse" id="buch">Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
                                        </td>

                                        <td data-th="Ausgabe" class="text-center align-middle h6">@buch.Ausgabe</td>
                                        <td data-th="ISBN" class="text-center align-middle h6">@buch.Isbn</td>
                                        <td data-th="Preis" class="text-center align-middle h6">@buch.PreisProTag.ToString("F2") €</td>
                                        <td data-th="Anzahl" class="text-center align-middle h6">@buch.Anzahl</td>
                                        <td data-th="Zeilenpreis" class="text-right align-middle h6">@buch.ZeilenPreisProTag.ToString("F2") €</td>

                                        <td class="actions align-middle" data-th="">
                                            <a class="btn btn-outline-danger " href="/Warenkorb/Entfernen?buchId=@buch.Id&anzahl=1" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                                                <i class="fa fa-lg fa-minus-square"></i>
                                            </a>
                                            <a class="btn btn-danger " href="/Warenkorb/Entfernen?buchId=@buch.Id&anzahl=@buch.Anzahl" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                                                <i class="fa fa-lg fa-cart-arrow-down"></i>
                                            </a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                }
                            </tbody>
                            <tfoot>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="5"></td>
                                    <td class="hidden-xs"><strong class="h4 text-primary">Gesamtpreis </strong></td>
                                    <td class="hidden-xs text-right"><strong class="h4 text-primary">  @Model.VmWarenkorbIndexListe.Sum(s => s.ZeilenPreisProTag).ToString("F2") €</strong></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <!-- ======================================== Schritt 2 - Ausleihdatum ======================================== -->
                                    <td> <a onclick="goBack()" class="btn btn-warning "><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i> Weiter einkaufen</a></td>
                                    <td colspan="6"></td>
                                    <td class="wizard-inner">
                                        <a href="#step2" title="Step 2" class="btn btn-success next-step">Jetzt Bestellen <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> </a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tfoot>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
            <!-- ======================================== Schritt 2 - Ausleihdatum ======================================== -->
            @Html.Partial("_Bestellen", Model)

            <!-- ======================================== Schritt 3 - Rechnung- und Lieferadresse ======================================== -->
            @Html.Partial("_Rechnungsdaten", Model)
            
            
              <!-- ======================================== Schritt 4 - Bezahlmöglichkeit ========================================
            <div class="tab-pane" role="tabpanel" id="step4">
                <h1 class="text-md-center">Step 4</h1>
                <div class="row">

                </div>
                <ul class="list-inline text-md-center">
                    <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-common next-step next-button">Next Step</button></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            -->
            @Html.Partial("_Danke")

        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

here is the Main View

and here is a partial view

```html
<div class="tab-pane text-center" role="tabpanel" id="step2">
    <h2>Ihre Bestellung </h2>
    <div class="row">


        @using (Html.BeginForm("Bestellen", "Warenkorb", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            <div class="container">
                <div></div>
                <table id="cart" class="table table-hover table-condensed ">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th style="width:20%" class="h4 text-left">@Html.DisplayName("Titel")</th>
                            <th class="text-center h5" style="width:20%">@Html.DisplayName("ISBN")</th>
                            <th class="text-left h5" style="width: 20%">@Html.DisplayName("Autoren")</th>
                            <th class="text-center h5" style="width: 5%">@Html.DisplayName("Ausgabe")</th>
                            <th class="text-center h5">@Html.DisplayName("Anzahl")</th>
                            <th class="text-center h5">@Html.DisplayName("Zeilenpreis")</th>
                            <th class="text-center h5">
                                @Html.DisplayName("Rückgabedatum")
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody class="border-bottom">
                        @foreach (var buch in Model.VmBestellen.Warenkorb)
                        {
                            <tr>

                                <td data-th="Buch" class="align-middle">
                                    <h6 class="nomargin text-left">@buch.Titel</h6>

                                </td>
                                <td data-th="ISBN" class="text-center align-middle h6">@buch.ISBN</td>
                                <td data-th="Autoren" class="align-middle h6">
                                    @foreach (var autor in buch.Autoren)
                                    {
                                        <span>@autor<br /></span>
                                    }
                                </td>
                                <td data-th="Ausgabe" class="text-center align-middle h6">@buch.Ausgabe</td>
                                <td data-th="Anzahl" class="text-center align-middle h6">@buch.Anzahl</td>
                                <td data-th="Zeilenpreis" class="text-right align-middle h6">@buch.ZeilenPreisProTagNetto.ToString("F2") €</td>

                                <td data-th="Datum">
                                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.VmBestellen.RueckgabeDatum, new { htmlAttributes = new { @type = "date", @name = "rueckgabedatum", @value = Model.VmBestellen.RueckgabeDatum.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy"), @class = "form-control" } })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.VmBestellen.RueckgabeDatum, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    <button type="submit" formmethod="get"> Datum ändern</button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                    </tbody>

                    <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="3" class="hidden-xs"></td>
                            <td class="hidden-xs" colspan="2"><strong class="h5 ">Preis  <strong class="h6">(exkl. Mwst)</strong>  </strong></td>
                            <td class="hidden-xs text-right"><strong class="h5 ">  @Model.VmBestellen.Warenkorb.Sum(s => s.ZeilenPreisProTagNetto).ToString("F2") €</strong></td>
                            <td class="hidden-xs"> <strong class="h5">Beginn: <bdi class="text-primary">@DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() </bdi></strong></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="3" class="hidden-xs"></td>
                            <td class="hidden-xs" colspan="2"><strong class="h6 ">Rabatt </strong></td>
                            <td class="hidden-xs text-right"><strong class="h6 "> - Rabatt -</strong></td>
                            <td class="hidden-xs"><strong class="h5">Ende: <bdi class="text-primary ">@Model.VmBestellen.RueckgabeDatum.ToShortDateString() </bdi></strong></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="3" class="hidden-xs"></td>
                            <td class="hidden-xs" colspan="2"><strong class="h6 ">Mwst </strong></td>
                            <td class="hidden-xs text-right"><strong class="h6 "> @Model.VmBestellen.MwstBetrag.ToString("F2") €</strong></td>
                            <td class="hidden-xs"><strong class="h5"> Tage Gesamt:  <bdi class="text-primary">XX</bdi> </strong> </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="3" class="hidden-xs"></td>
                            <td class="hidden-xs" colspan="2"><strong class="h4 text-primary">Preis <strong class="h6 text-primary">(inkl. Mwst)</strong> </strong></td>
                            <td class="hidden-xs text-right"><strong class="h4 text-primary"> @Model.VmBestellen.GesamtpreisBrutto.ToString("F2") €</strong></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <!-- ======================================== Schritt 3 - Abschluss ========================================-->
                            <td > <a onclick="goBack()"  class="btn btn-warning btn-block "><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i> Zurück zum Warenkorb</a></td>
                            <td colspan="5"></td>
                            <td class="wizard-inner">                              
                                <a href="~/Warenkorb#step3" title="Step 3" class="btn btn-success next-step btn-block" onclick="bestellen()">Bestellung abschließen <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>


                    </tfoot>
                </table>
            </div>

        }
    </div>
</div>
```

here is the a href - which calls at the moment only a link - but i would need to call the link AND with the same click call an POST-ActionResult

i thought i could call the POST ActionResult and from there Redirect to a specific #id

Comment: Any code you could provide?

Comment: Can you please share what you try?